# How do I format the NavBar Bootstrap 4 Layout with a custom layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor, bootstrap-4

Good Evening all,

I am developing a web site for a customer, he has given me a brief on how he would like the Nar Bar to look.  At first, it looked easy but as always I have spent a number of hours trying to find the answer.
I am using the `Visual Studio 2019 community`, the web pages are being designed with `Razor` and I am using `Bootstrap 4` as a base CSS. I am designing this mobile-first and have got pretty much the layout correct but need your help, if I may. I actually have two questions, but I am happy to start another thread if the second question isn't relevant here.

I am using a very basic `out-of-the-box` Bootstrap NavBar, but I am having an issue with one of the elements.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="~/Images/Logo.png" /></a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse p-3" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 border-right">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">News</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Car Sales</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">MOT</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item pb-3">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mx-auto">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Book an Appointment</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I have a small amount of custom CSS to override some styles from Bootstrap.

```
nav {
    padding - bottom: 15 px!important;
}
.navbar {
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: -moz - linear - gradient(180 deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0 % , rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 95 % , rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100 % );
    background: -webkit - linear - gradient(180 deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0 % , rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 95 % , rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100 % );
    background: linear - gradient(180 deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0 % , rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 95 % , rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100 % );
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr = "#000000", endColorstr = "#ffffff", GradientType = 1);
}

.navbar - brand img {
    max - height: 105 px;
}
```

Which produces this, [Mobile Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIHOc.jpg) which is how the customer wants it.

When I increase the screen size to more than 456px the Book an Appointment link moves up and to the right of the hamburger button. So my question is, what is the best way to keep it under the Logo and the hamburger until I get to 576px where my layout changes, which sort of leads me into my next question.

If the user is using a tablet or desktop, then I need the Navbar to change the look, I have an idea on how to do it but would like to see if there is a more eloquent way of doing it.
This is how it should look on the tablet / desktop [Desktop Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhrTl.jpg) and this is the code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-7">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                    <img src="~/Images/Logo.png" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-5 d-md-none">
                <button class="navbar-toggler float-right bg-white" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsedmenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-10 col-12">
                <div id="collapsedmenu" class="row collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav top-menu">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">News</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Car Sales</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                            </li>

                            <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="contact-number">
                            <a href="tel:00000000000">
                                <span>Call Us:</span> 00000 000000
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav service-menu">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Book an Appointment</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">MOT</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

So my second question is, is there an easy to make the Navbar responsive and show the two different layouts? I was going to hide the Desktop  code when in Moblie with `.d-sm-none .d-md-block` and then show it if we are using a desktop. I am completely open to suggestions and can hopefully answer any questions you have.

#### EDIT: Complete Nav Code with Update from Nisharg

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="text-center">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="~/Images/Logo.png" /></a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Book an Appointment</a>
        </div>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        @*Hide on bigger than Mobile (sm)*@
        <div class="d-sm-none">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse p-3" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6 border-right">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item active">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">News</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Car Sales</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">MOT</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item pb-3">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                            </li>
                            <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        @*
        <div class="mx-auto">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Book an Appointment</a>
        </div>*@ 

        @*Hide on Mobile (sm)*@
        <div class="d-none d-sm-block">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav top-menu">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">News</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Car Sales</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                        </li>

                        <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="contact-number">
                        <a href="tel:00000000000">
                            <span>Call Us:</span> 00000 000000
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav service-menu">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Book an Appointment</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">MOT</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I suggest to make code like that, so with one code you can manage both screens

Comment: can you make snippet of your both screen?

Comment: Thanks, @NishargShah but that is sort of my question, how do I do that? Obviously I don't really want to duplicate my code as this could cause problems with the URLs if they change.

Comment: To fulfill your 2nd question need, I need a working snippet from your side because from that I do an experiment in it and give it final result to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1st Solution

I removed the last `book appointment` text and add it with `logo`.

Now in all resolution, your `book appointment` text is below the logo.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark">
    <div class="image_wrapepr">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img class="w-100" src="PDFs/img/lol1.jpg" /></a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Book an Appointment</a>
    </div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse p-3" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 border-right">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">News</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Car Sales</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">MOT</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item pb-3">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, Nisharg, Your 1st solution is a lot better, would like the book appointment to be centred on screen rather than just under the logo. I guess that will be playing with the css to get that right.

Comment: I have edited my original question with complete ```nav``` code and your 1st solution answer as well.  ```text-center``` only centres the  text under the logo, unless I have misunderstood you, thank you for your help so far

Comment: Yes sorry, I would like it centred on the navbar.